# How to move Git commits to another branch and delete them in the original branch?

Tags: git

I have the following commits in a branch now:

[image]

I mistakenly started Branch B work and have committed `b58`, `151` and `5ef` in Branch A.

Those 3 commits supposed to be in the Branch B and not in the Branch A. All 3 commits have been pushed to my remote Git server.

**My question**

How do I move those 3 commits to Branch B and delete them in Branch A? For the Branch B, I want it to branch off from commit `97b` in the Branch A.

Comment: use a cherry picking function. so you can pick your commits and merge them into correct branch. but you should also remove commits in a wrong branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create the branch B now  and then reset branch A to the state you want it to be, and then you will need to force push it to the remote server.

```
git checkout -b branchB
git checkout branchA
git reset --hard HEAD~3
git push -f
```

Check the status with git log and git status all the way along.

Answer (score 0):

If branch B doesn't already exist and you don't have other work on branch A, you can write

```
git checkout a
git branch b
git reset --hard 97b
```

That will create B to point to the current A and then set A to 97b.  Note that if you push A, you'll need to force push by doing `git push origin +a`.

If you have other work on branch B, you can do

```
git checkout b
git cherry-pick 5ef 161 b58b
git checkout a
git reset --hard 97b
```

You'll need to do a force push for a here as well.